Effectively hiding IP
Context: Consider the scenario in which you want to hide your ISP IP address from the application service you are accessing/using.
Possible solutions: In general, three scenarios for trying to accomplish this task may be employed:

Using a third-party VPN service, where the VPN provider still has the power of disclosing, case the company adopts a logging policy, the ISP IP address;
Hosting a VPN in a third-party VPS service, where the same weakness manifests by the side of the VPS provider; And
Hosting a VPN in my own self-hosted and physically maintained VPS, where would require physical infrastructure for such.

Is my reasoning right? Is the last option the only really effective?
For didactic purposes, I am ignoring the Tor network alternative.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Community, let me know if the changes suffices.

So by necessity in IP systems, an IP address has to be visible to the network. Any intermediary may be recording traffic (subject to their local legal system as to when this is banned, allowed, or required).
That means there has to be a node somewhere which:

knows what your ultimate other end of communication is

knows at least one "hop" back down the chain towards you


And that node needs to be in a real location subject to physical law enforcement. Tor just expands this by providing an automatically configured chain of forwarding nodes, in the hope that obfuscates traffic sufficiently.
Your option (3) just moves the "attack" point to your own VPS.
In practice, law-evading systems either use uncooperative jurisdictions (e.g. Russia) or compromised third party nodes (such as consumer routers) which are not aware that they are facilitating crime.

Thank you so much. That was exactly the answer I was looking for. In those OPSEC forums I couldn't find any honest answer about it.

I just didn't upvoted your answer because I do not, yet, have enough reputation skills.
